# Handle "any" field in wsdl schema using java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsimport

I generate my pojo class with wsdl using "wsimport" successfully. But the wsdl schema have "any" fields. The fields generate as "Object" in my java class.

The wsdl schema :

```
<s:complexType name="Model1"> 
  <s:sequence>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Model2">
       <s:complexType>
         <s:sequence>
           <s:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" processContents="lax"/>
           <s:any minOccurs="1" namespace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" processContents="lax"/>
         </s:sequence>
       </s:complexType>
    </s:element>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Response" type="s:string"/>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Response_Str" type="s:string"/>
   </s:sequence>
 </s:complexType>
 ...
 ...
```

The generated Class using wsimport:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Model1", propOrder = {
        "model2",
        "response",
        "responseStr"
})
public class Model1 {

    @XmlElement(name = "Model2")
    protected Object model2;
    @XmlElement(name = "Response")
    protected String response;
    @XmlElement(name = "Response_Str")
    protected String responseStr;
```

The Model2's schema comes in response as follow:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <Response xmlns="...">
         <Result>
            <Model2>
               <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
                  <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="Temp" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
                     <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                           <xs:element name="Temp">
                              <xs:complexType>
                                 <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="field1" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                                    <xs:element name="field2" msdata:DataType="System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                    ...
                                    ...
                                    ...
                                 </xs:sequence>
                              </xs:complexType>
                           </xs:element>
                        </xs:choice>
                     </xs:complexType>
                  </xs:element>
               </xs:schema>
               <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
                  <NewDataSet xmlns="">
                     <Temp diffgr:id="Temp1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
                        <ID>20018243</ID>
```

Wsdl does not exist Model2's schema , but the schema is in the response.

How can I handle the schema in java?

How can I cast the response to "Object model2"?

Comment: I don't think that you can handle this in Java, at least not with the standard tools. There are plenty of Microsoft extensions used. I doubt that anything outside .NET will understand it.

Comment: Maybe I can use a custom xml parser

Comment: Perhaps, but it will be a very brittle solution. The schema gives very few guarantees. If you parse one response successfully that doesn't mean that the next response will work. If possible try to get another and more portable API.